# Enforce invertiblity of an MA(q) process with non-unit coefficient

Tags: time-series, arima, moving-average

Consider the MA(p) process

$ y_t = \theta_0 \varepsilon_t + \theta_1 \varepsilon_{t-1} + \ldots + + \theta_q \varepsilon_{t-q}   $,

where $\theta_0 \neq 1$, contrary to the convention taken in most textbooks, and $\varepsilon \sim i.i.d.  N(0,\sigma^2)$.

The goal is to restrict the coefficients $\theta_i, i = 0, \ldots, q$ in estimation to satisfy invertibility of the process. Monahan (1984, Biometrika) shows how this can be done for ARMA(p,q) processes where $\theta_0 = 1$ by reparameterizing the process in terms of partial autocorrelations.

My take so far has been to rewrite $y_t$ as:

$y_t = (1+\tilde{\theta}_1 L + \ldots + \tilde{\theta}_q L^q) \tilde{\varepsilon}_t ,$

where $\tilde{\theta}_i \equiv \frac{\theta_i}{\theta_0}$ and $\tilde{\varepsilon} \sim i.i.d.  N(0,\theta_0^2 \sigma^2)$. This representation allows to use the Monahan reparameterization. However, it also changes the variance of $\varepsilon_t$ which is something I don't want.

Any hints on how to adapt this method to the present case will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Following up on my approach, suppose $(1+ \tilde{\theta}_1 L + \ldots + \tilde{\theta}_q L^q)$ is invertible. What are the conditions on $\theta_0$ so that the original process is invertible?

Comment: So if $(1+\tilde{\theta} L + \ldots + \tilde{\theta}_q L^q)$ is invertible, we have $(1+ \eta_1 L + \eta_2 L^2 + \ldots) y_t = \theta_0 \varepsilon_t$, where $(1+ \eta_1 L + \eta_2 L^2 + \ldots) = (1+\tilde{\theta} L + \ldots + \tilde{\theta}_q L^q)^{-1}$. If $\theta_0 \neq 1$, an AR($\infty$) process obtains in $\frac{1}{\theta_0}y_t$ with innovation $\varepsilon_t$. I am still wondering whether it is possible to get an AR($\infty$) representation for $y_t$ with innovation $\varepsilon_t$.